# Inverse of Heyting algebra morphism is p-morphism

Tags: reference-request, heyting-algebra

It is known that the category of Heyting algebras is dually equivalent to the category of Esakia spaces (which is equivalent to the category of descriptive intuitionistic Kripke frames). Under the duality, a Heyting morphism $f : H \to H'$ is send to its inverse, that is it sends a prime filter in $H'$ to its inverse image.

**Question:** Why is this inverse map a p-morphism (or bounded morphism)?

All references I have found for this refer to a paper by Esakia himself, in Russian. I am looking for an English reference or a proof.

Comment: Check out Lemma 5.5 of Patrick Morandi's excellent [notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bmVAc09VXiobliT1PgyL1cX_2Tv4iGpo/view) on duality theory for distributive lattices and Heyting algebras.

Comment: I'd found them indeed. Thanks!

Comment: For a somewhat different type of argument you can also have a look at Theorem 6 of the paper [Canonical extensions, Esakia spaces, and
universal models](https://www.irif.fr/~mgehrke/Ge12.pdf) by Mai Gehrke.